# why flask code not giving dictionary values in web page

Tags: python, flask, request.form

Why I am getting an empty dict in web page after running this code?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/multiplication')
def multi():
    data = request.form
    print('data is',data)
    return f'data is {data}'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I pass values as `a = 10`, `b= 5` through postman app, its showing correct dictionary in powershell
but in the web page it's showing empty dict.

I tried above code to get the dictionary `{'a' : '10' , 'b' : '5'}`
but instead getting `{}` empty dict in web page

Comment: How are you accessing the route? HTML form with a POST request? If so, can you edit your post to include the HTML/JS?

Comment: @Rob, I am accessing through postman app form-data to send values

Comment: Okay, so what do you mean when you say "in the web page it's showing an empty dict"? You mean you're navigating to `/multiplication` in your web browser?